# Android Emulator (AVD ) on Core2Duo processor with windows 8.1

Tags: android

I am novice to Android development. Recently installed android studio and trying to have AVD up and running. Here is what i have

Windows 8.1 Pro

Android Studio 0.8.14

Android SDK Tools : 23.0.5

Android SDK Build Tools : 21.1.1

Android Platform-tools : 21

Since i want to use JellyBeans i installed Android 4.1.2 (API 16 ) ( installed all 7 modules )

Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) installed.
Usb driver installed.

When i try to install HAXM i get following error

[image]

I was reading release notes for HAXM and found following. Under known issue section

**-HAXM driver does not support emulating a 64 bit system image on Intel systems based on Core microarchitecture (Core, Core2 Duo etc.). All systems based on Nehalem and beyond are supported. (Corei3, Core i5 and Core i7 machines).**

Q : Is there ANY other way i can run AVD without buying a new Computer ?? It looks like i have to buy a computer with Coreix series processor ??

Answer (score 1):

Your processor doesn't support Intel Virtualization technology support which is needed to launch emulator. Intel Core2 duo 8400 does support this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the core thing. But I was able to use it after uninstalling hyper-v. You can do so in turn on/off Windows features.

Comment: i don't see Hyper-v installed on my system. Do you have Intel i series processor ? Which processor do you have ?

Comment: I have i7. You mean you see that the hyper V is unchecked or you don't see that option at all?

Comment: Yea Hyper-V is unchecked. I think its because of Core2Duo processor that i have. Seems either i have to directly deploy and test my application on android device or i have to upgrade my machine to AVD up and running.

Comment: According to this website: http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology Your cpu does not support VT. That's the requirement for HAXM to work.