# How to run android official emulators on a Intel core CPU?

Tags: android, android-emulator, qemu

I have a pc that is okay for test development and it consists an Intel core cpu.
As qemu emulator wont run on this family of CPU. So only option is using other virtualization softwares and emulators like Genymotion.

### But how can I run the official emulator on this family of CPU?

Comment: `qemu emulator wont run on this family of CPU` why you think so? why you think that it won't run on Intel? That's wrong.

Comment: I've seen more before but now found this link. According to this link, HAXM driver does not support emulating 64 bit system image on Intel systems based on Core microarchitecture (Core, Core2 Duo etc.). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833650/android-emulator-avd-on-core2duo-processor-with-windows-8-1

Comment: this means that you still can use 32-bit images. And this is only about Core CPUs, not about entire Intel.

Comment: If you know what a family is than the question is good to explain. Why you think its about entire Intel... Thanks for commenting.

Comment: `And this is only about Core CPUs, not about entire Intel` I **don't** think that it's about entire Intel. But I misread your question, I thought that you say that it's about entire Intel.